# IQueryable extension to group dynamicly by minutes ...and other

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, expression, iqueryable

I wanted to create an `IQueryable` extension to allow other developers to group entities by minutely interval but also by custom group key result.

My idea was to create a method with the following signature:

```
public static IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> GroupByMinutelyTimePeriode<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source
            , Expression<Func<DateTime, TSource, TKey>> keySelector
            , Func<TSource, DateTime> timestampSelector
            , int minutes)
{
```

Something that you can use just like this example:

```
var query = dataContext.Datas
   .Where(d => d.Timestamp >= lowerTimestampRange && d.Timestamp < upperTimestampRange)
   
   ////// extension /////
   .GroupByMinutelyTimePeriode((t, d) => new
   {
       DeviceId = d.DeviceId,
       TimestampBoundary = t
   }
   , d => d.Date
   , 15)
   /////////////////////
   
   .Select(g => new
   {
       DeviceId = g.Key.DeviceId,
       Date = g.Key.TimestampBoundary,
       Value = g.Sum(d => d.Value)
   });
```

Within the extension something like this should happens (for sure not working because not translateable by linq-to-sql):

```
public static IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> GroupByMinutelyTimePeriode<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source
            , Func<DateTime, TSource, TKey> keySelector
            , Func<TSource, DateTime> timestampSelector
            , int minutes)
    {
        return source.GroupBy(d => keySelector(new DateTime(timestampSelector(d).Year
            , timestampSelector(d).Month
            , timestampSelector(d).Day
            , timestampSelector(d).Hour
            , timestampSelector(d).Minute / minutes * minutes, 0)
            , d
            ));
    }
```

I must say I completely failed to translate this into a proper working `IQueryable` expression syntax. I try to understand how to work with Expressions from existing `IQueryable` extensions like `GroupBy` from GitHub.

Maybe someone can help me to find a good example.

Comment: From my experience with LINQ to SQL I have strong doubts that you'll find a statement that can be translated - but I hope it for you anyways  does client-side execution blow your app into pieces?

Comment: First make it work, then think about extensions. This question should therefore focus on "make it work" part, both in title and in the content. For instance, don't mention extensions at all.

Comment: Your API seems overly complex to me - why not have (effect of) `GroupBy(d => new { Key = keySelector(d), timestampSelector(d).Year, timestampSelector(d).Month, timestampSelector(d).Day, timestampSelector(d).Hour, Minute = timestampSelector(d).Minute / minutes * minutes })` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but instead of `Func<,>` you have to pass `Expression<Func<,>>` as parameters. Only in this case you can reuse selectors body.

Some magic with Expression Tree transformation:

```cs
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> GroupByMinutlyTimePeriode<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source
        , Expression<Func<DateTime, TSource, TKey>> keySelector
        , Expression<Func<TSource, DateTime>> timestampSelector
        , int minutes)
    {
        Expression<Func<DateTime, int, DateTime>> dateTimeTemplate = (t, m) => new DateTime(t.Year
            , t.Month
            , t.Day
            , t.Hour
            , t.Minute / m * m, 0);

        var entityParam = keySelector.Parameters[1];

        var dateTimeBody =
            ExpressionReplacer.GetBody(dateTimeTemplate, ExpressionReplacer.GetBody(timestampSelector, entityParam), Expression.Constant(minutes));

        var keyBody = ExpressionReplacer.GetBody(keySelector, dateTimeBody, entityParam);
        var keyLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TKey>>(keyBody, entityParam);

        return source.GroupBy(keyLambda);
    }


    class ExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        readonly IDictionary<Expression, Expression> _replaceMap;

        public ExpressionReplacer(IDictionary<Expression, Expression> replaceMap)
        {
            _replaceMap = replaceMap ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(replaceMap));
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
        {
            if (node != null && _replaceMap.TryGetValue(node, out var replacement))
                return replacement;
            return base.Visit(node);
        }

        public static Expression Replace(Expression expr, Expression toReplace, Expression toExpr)
        {
            return new ExpressionReplacer(new Dictionary<Expression, Expression> { { toReplace, toExpr } }).Visit(expr);
        }

        public static Expression Replace(Expression expr, IDictionary<Expression, Expression> replaceMap)
        {
            return new ExpressionReplacer(replaceMap).Visit(expr);
        }

        public static Expression GetBody(LambdaExpression lambda, params Expression[] toReplace)
        {
            if (lambda.Parameters.Count != toReplace.Length)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            return new ExpressionReplacer(Enumerable.Range(0, lambda.Parameters.Count)
                .ToDictionary(i => (Expression)lambda.Parameters[i], i => toReplace[i])).Visit(lambda.Body);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like `ExpressionReplacer` - nice improvement over typical single `Expression` replace visitor.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv Fails with :(

`The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Data>()
    .Where(d => d.Timestamp >= __lower_1 && d.Timestamp < __upper_2)
    .GroupBy(
        keySelector: d => new {
            DeviceId = d.DeviceId,
            Boundary = new DateTime(
                d.Timestamp.Year,
                d.Timestamp.Month,
                d.Timestamp.Day,
                d.Timestamp.Hour,
                d.Timestamp.Minute / 15 * 15,
                0
            )
         },
        elementSelector: d => d)' could not be translated.
`

Query looks good for me.

Comment: Show how do you use that.

Comment: @Svyatoslav [...]
                    `.Where(d => d.Timestamp >= lower && d.Timestamp < upper)
                    .GroupByMinutlyTimePeriode((t, d) => new
                    {
                        DeviceId = d.DeviceId,
                        Boundary = t
                    },
                    d => d.Timestamp,
                    15)
                    .Select(g => new
                    {
                        DeviceId = g.Key.DeviceId,
                        Date = g.Key.Boundary,
                        Value = g.Sum(d => d.Value)
                    });`

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv do you have any idea why its not working, I was not able to. :(

Comment: @SteffenMangold, sorry about that. Fixed answer.